# Is it possible to output Meteor function in the dev console?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to simulate the 'button press' without using the `UI`. To do this I need to create a function that later can be called from the developer's console.

I was trying to use `Meteor.methods` syntax like this:

```
// this code is in `server/index.js`

Meteor.methods({ 
  hello: () => 'hello';
})
```

And typing in dev console `Meteor.call('hello')` &  `Meteor.methods.call('hello')`. Both returned `undefined`

I'm aware that being able to call meteor methods from the dev console may in some cases be considered a bad practice, but I need this one for the debug purposes.

**Update**

The end goal is to have a button that is when pressed will fetch data from user's `github` account (if they have one). Because this task includes multiple steps (i.e. set up GitHub's `OAuth`, fetch data, have some kind of a UI, etc.) I decided to split the task into several smaller tasks.

I already can fetch data for a one user (it is hard-coded for now), now my goal is to simulate the button click by typing in a client's console a Meteor's function (because I don't know what library or framework I'm going to use for a front-end )

My example with `hello` is a simplified version of what I want to achieve at this point.

Comment: You mean the client's dev console? Beware, that methods on the client return their results via callback.

Comment: @Jankapunkt yes, client's dev console

Comment: Why would you need to go through Meteor's backend? A simple `document.querySelector("...").click()` sounds good enough

Comment: @aletzo the thing is that for now there is almost no UI at all.

Comment: So you're trying to simulate a button press but there's no button? Could you describe a bit more what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @aletzo I've updated my question; please, take a look

Comment: So you just want to output in the dev console something from the backend. Have you tried something like this: `Meteor.call('hello', (err, res) => console.log(res));`?

Comment: Meteor.call is async function so it will work with callback not like console.log(Meteor.call('hello'))

Answer (score 0):

```
Meteor.call('hello', function(error, result){
 if(err){console.log(err)}
 else {
   console.log(result) // result in hello
 }
});
```